# Generating permutations using generators

Tags: python, iterator, generator, permutation, yield

I was writing a program to generate all the permutations of a string:

```
def print_permutations_wrapper(str):
    strList = str.split()
    print_permutations(strList, 0, len(strList))


def print_permutations(strList: list, start: int, end: int):
    if start >= end - 1:
        print(strList)
        return

    print_permutations(strList, start+1, end)
    for i in range(start+1, end):
        strList[start], strList[i] = strList[i], strList[start]
        print_permutations(strList, start+1, end)
        strList[i], strList[start] = strList[start], strList[i]


def main():
    str = 'a b c'
    print_permutations_wrapper(str)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Its working correctly, but rather than printing it, I wanted to return it lazily using `yield`:

```
def print_permutations_wrapper(str):
    strList = str.split()
    yield from print_permutations(strList, 0, len(strList))


def print_permutations(strList: list, start: int, end: int):
    if start >= end - 1:
        yield strList
        return

    yield from print_permutations(strList, start+1, end)
    for i in range(start+1, end):
        strList[start], strList[i] = strList[i], strList[start]
        yield from print_permutations(strList, start+1, end)
        strList[i], strList[start] = strList[start], strList[i]


def main():
    str = 'a b c'
    x = print_permutations_wrapper(str)
    print(list(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output that I get is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

rather than all the permutations.
How to correct this?

I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: You are mutating the same `strList`, thus the result will be a list of the same list.  You can try to `yield list(strList)` in `print_permutations` to create a shallow copy of that list, or make use of the built-in [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), which the documentation include example implementation.  Also see related [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @metatoaster `yield list(strList)` yields a deep copy of that list, not a shallow copy.

Comment: Oh its working now.. thanks! You might want to write it in the answer. Interesting link. Definitely astonishing for a beginner!

Comment: @AlbinPaul `list` does not recursively duplicate any internal references that may be part of the list of references that it received from the argument.  It only touches the top-level elements - you need [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for what you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your second program, but add a `print(strList)` will show that the generator function yielded what you expected, but the final output is clearly not what you expected.  This is due to the fact that the program as structured takes a list, but does all the operation to this same copy (assumed to limit memory usage).  You can also verify this by

```
>>> strList = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> items = list(print_permutations(strList, 0, 3))
>>> items[0] is items[1]
True
>>> items[0] is strList
True
```

Clearly every single item inside the `items` are of the same original `strList` that got passed in.  Given the simplicity of the problem, this may be avoided by yielding a shallow copy of the list instead.  Thus the relevant `yield` part of the function will become

```
def print_permutations(strList: list, start: int, end: int):
    if start >= end - 1:
        yield list(strList)
        return
```

Now running it should produce:

```
>>> strList = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> items = list(print_permutations(strList, 0, 3))
>>> items[0] is items[1]
False
```

Also, as an aside, permutation is in fact a part of the standard library, available via [`itertools.permutation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Related: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)